# HAML DRY if in loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, zurb-foundation

I am having trouble with HAML and Foundation. I want to generate a list of people sort of in a google plus card style. What I tried:

```
- @people.each_with_index do |person, index|
  - if index.even?
    .row
      .panel.medium-6.small-12.columns
        %h3= person.full_name
        %h5 more metadata
  - else
    .panel.medium-6.small-12.columns
      %h3= person.full_name
      %h5 more metadata
```

Besides this not working because the tags are on the wrong levels, it's also not exactly DRY. Any idea on how to correctly do this maybe even in a more DRY way?

Comment: How should the markup differ between rows? Apart from `.row`, they appear to be exactly the same. What do you mean by "tags are on wrong levels"?

Comment: I want every two panels grouped in a row for responsiveness. When I do it the way I described, I generate code where every second panel is surrounded by the row element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, what I'd do is use [`enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) to pair the results:

```
- @people.each_slice(2).each do |pair|
    .row
      - pair.each do |person|
        .panel.medium-6.small-12.columns
          %h3= person.full_name
          %h5 more metadata
```

Comment: @apneadiving could you please elaborate?

Comment: @apneadiving please read his comments, as I mentioned in my answer. "I want every two panels grouped in a row for responsiveness". My answer is correct. BTW -- love gmaps4rails! :)

Comment: My bad! Then I'd just say `to_a` is unnecessary :) +1